# PHP : calculate day difference between stored datetime in mysql and current datetime for token expiry

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I am storing token creation time into mysql `datetime`

```
$date = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata'));
$datetime = $date->format('d-m-Y H:i:s');
```

and then while checking token expiry, I want to see if token is older than 20 days.Probably, `diff()` in PHP would do it, but how can I calculate difference in days? Or is there any better way?

**EDIT**

When I am inserting `$datetime` in mysql, PHP is inserting `0000-00-00 00:00:00` . Why?
I tried `strtotime($datetime)` also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `diff()` method of a `DateTime` object returns an instance of `DateInterval`, which has a property named `days` that is exactly what you want:

```
$date = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata'));
$diff = $date->diff($otherDate);
if ($diff->days > 20) {
    // token expired, error...
}
```

Comment: @InsaneCoder MySQL's datetime format is YYYY-mm-dd not dd-mm-YYYY. Try `$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')`.

Comment: No still I am getting all 0's

Comment: @InsaneCoder Perhaps you should post this as a separate question then. `0000-00-00 00:00:00` just means that you passed a somehow invalid value. But without the code for the actual query it's hard to tell why.